# Bibliography and citations don't work on IEEE or Vancouver style

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I feel desperate and about to give up LaTeX. I am new to it but I have done well until I reach the bibliography. Now I am stuck for days and I have a deadline. I am sure I have a problem with my codes, but I keep getting different error messages. Once it worked until the `\cite{author}` but worked on some and not the others. Now nothing works.

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtr}
\usepackage[margin=1in,left=1.5in, includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{parskip}
\setlength\parindent{24pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.08}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{natbib}
\setcitestyle{numbers}
\usepackage{filecontents}


%Graphics preamble
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{5pt}

%header and footer stuff
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[R]{ \thepage\ }

%
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
   \centering
   \huge{\bfseries  mettle}\\
   \vspace{1 cm}
 \large\ Author 1, Author 2, Author 3\\
   \vspace{1 cm}
   \textsc{mysubtitle}\\

\end{titlepage}

% Abstract page
\pagenumbering{roman}
\section*{Abstract}\label{sec:abs}



\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\numberline{}Abstract}
\cleardoublepage

% table of content page
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}
\cleardoublepage

%list of figures
\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures}
\cleardoublepage

% Main document
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\section{Introduction}\label{sec:intro}

TEXT
\section{heading}
\section{conclusion}
\newpage

\section{References}
\bibliography{references}{}

\cleardoublepage
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your code as it stands will have no bibliography due to a lack of `\cite` or `\nocite` commands.  If the issue is more than this, please add in some `\cite`s and update your code in the question along with the associated `bib` entry.  If you are getting errors, please either provide code (as a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4407)) which we can compile locally to replicate the errors or provide the text of the error.

Comment: "Nothing works" is not a sensible problem description. Check http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/bugs.html to learn how to improve your question.

Comment: Have you run `pdflatex`, `bibtex`, and then again `pdflatex` twice? Please give us an example of your `.bib` file, I tried with an example `.bib` file and you code works.

Comment: bibtex error message: 
Warning--entry type for "Eurorec" isn't style-file defined
--line 18 of file references.bib
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "(Bodenheimer"

Comment: Have you those entries in your `references.bib` file? Could you add how they are defined in it?

Comment: Example:@url{Eurorec,
 Date-Added = {2017-02-19 16:11:14 +0000},
 Date-Modified = {2017-02-19 16:11:53 +0000},
 Title = {EuroRec},
 Url = {http://www.eurorec.org/whoarewe/introduction.cfm}}

Comment: this worked: run pdflatex, bibtex, and then again pdflatex twice? Please give us an example of your .bib file. But one citation appear as (?)

Comment: @Asma if one citation appears as `[?]` then the key is likely mistyped either in the main document or in the `bib` file (or the entry is missing altogether from the `bib` file) possibly from your second bibtex warning you gave earlier, you have `(Bodenheimer` in the `tex` file where you mean to have `Bodenheimer`.  Otherwise it sounds like this is the same as [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/106162) - it's always necessary to do the `pdflatex bibtex pdflatex pdflatex` chain to get references to show up properly.

Comment: Is there any particular reason for using the `IEEEtr` bibliography style? I ask because the `IEEEtr` style is more than 25 years old and is not programmed fields named, say, `url` and `date-added`. At the very least, you should try using one of the newer IEEE bibliography styles.

Answer (score 1):

(too long for a comment, hence posted as an anwer)

The following, much-condensed version of your example code, "works" in the sense that a bibliographic entry and a corresponding citation call-out are produced by running pdflatex, bibtex, and pdflatex twice more.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@url{Eurorec,
  date-added   = "2017-02-19 16:11:14 +0000",
  date-modified= "2017-02-19 16:11:53 +0000",
  title        = "EuroRec",
  url          = "eurorec.org/whoarewe/introduction.cfm",
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtr}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{natbib}
\setcitestyle{numbers}

\begin{document}
\cite{Eurorec}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

Note that the formatted entry will show only 1 field: `title`. This is because the `IEEEtr` bibliography style, being slightly archaic, is not programmed to recognize the fields named `url`, `date-added`, and `date-modified`. It doesn't recognize the entry type `@url` either; however, it is programmed to treat all unrecognized entry types as being of type `@misc` -- the catch-all entry type.

Comment: I am still struggling with bibliography. citations are now in place but the bib style is odd. I get a citation of g o b o Swedish. Even though the entry is as follows: @techreport{Gartner,
 Author = {Gartner on behalf of Swedish Ministry of Health and Social Affairs},
 Date-Added = {2017-02-19 12:42:47 +0000},
 Date-Modified = {2017-02-19 12:47:39 +0000},
 Institution = {Swedish Ministry of Health and Social Affairs},
 Title = {eHealth for a Healthier Europe!},
 Year = {2009}}

Comment: @Asma - Here's a case of a "corporate" author: Economics ncase the author field in double pairs of curly braces. Search this site for "corporate author" for more information on this subject...